# Use my variable outside of method JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I'm still learning and I have a little question.

I have three links and I want to know which link I gave click. So, this are my links:

```
<ul id="links">
   <li><a id="map-1" href="#">Mapa 1</a></li>
   <li><a id="map-2" href="#">Mapa 2</a></li>
   <li><a id="map-3" href="#">Mapa 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is my JS

```
var currentLink;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#links a").each(function(){
       $(this).on("click", function(e){
          return currentLink= $(this).attr("id");   
          console.log(currentLink); //This works 'cause I know the ID of my current link
       });
   });
}); 
console.log(currentLink); //I lost the value of my link
```

Someone can explain what I'm missing?
Thanks a lot!!

:)

Comment: why you are using that return just affect it like this currentLink= $(this).attr("id");

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do? The last log will run before user ever clicks on anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Your question is not clear but here is what is happening
> - You need to tell us what exactly you are looking for
>
> **See my comments near each line**

```
/* Variable is defined here*/
var currentLink;

/*document ready, means this executes after your page is loaded and dom is ready*/
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#links a").each(function(){
       $(this).on("click", function(e){
          return currentLink= $(this).attr("id");   
          console.log(currentLink); /***This is wrong, not sure how it works, after you return something this line is not supposed to be executed.***/
       });
   });
}); 

//This gets executed immediately before document ready is ran, probably first
console.log(currentLink); //YOUR VALUE IS NEVER assigned here while it is executing
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps.

```
// This line runs first.
var currentLink;

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#links a").each(function () {
       $(this).on("click", function (e) {
          // This line runs third.
          return currentLink = $(this).attr("id");
          console.log(currentLink); // This never runs, since there's a "return" above it.
       });
   });
}); 

// This line runs second.
console.log(currentLink);
```

**EDIT**

To elaborate: first you create the variable. Then you set up a click handler. Then you log the value of the variable. Then sometime in the future, when someone clicks on a link, your click handler actually runs, and you assign a value to that variable (long after your `console.log` executed).

Comment: Last log will run before event occurs...makes no sense. Also nothing asynchronous about a click event

Comment: But the last console.log (outside of function) says: undefined.

Comment: Right. Because it runs right after `var currentLink;` but before anything has been assigned to it.

Comment: Yeah... exactly, outside of function. It won't be defined until the function is run.

Comment: People who down-voted this, guys he is saying what all you are saying. But, his explanation are not clear. It needs an edit.